# Upload file not working when using ip address instead of localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i try to upload an image in my project using localhost it's working but when i try to use my IP address instead it's not working. 
For example, I tried the following:

```
 localhost/my-project/upload
```

Which works. However,

```
 192.192.52.2/my-project/upload
```

does not work.

Are there any solutions for this issue?

So can anyone tell me what should be the issue when using IP address instead of localhost in php.

Comment: I assume that you are on your own computer and not a actual server, the reason is (most likely at least), is that your "local server" is not setup to respond to the IP. / i.e the IP doesn't send the request to the local server.

Comment: so what is the solution of this issue?

Comment: Get the IP to route to your local host / Make the localhost respond to the IP.

Comment: is there any setting in xampp?

Comment: Does this produce any errors in the upload class? Does it produce any other errors at all? Can you describe what it is actually doing (apart from it doesn't work because that doesn't help)? Can you show any code examples? When you say using the IP is it the same server as localhost or is this your remote server? If you can answer these questions and provide as much data as possible the community might be able to help! Its much better that everyone guessing until someone finally gets it right. ;-)

Comment: 1)Not Produce any error in upload class
2)Not Produce any other error
3)when i upload it just load but upload image
5)same server

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this. First go to your folder.
Example: (C:)xampp/htdocs/yourfoldername/application/config/config.php

Open config.php. And add this


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/

 $config['base_url'] = 'http://192.192.52.2/yourfoldername/'; 

or

 $config['base_url'] = 'http://192.192.52.2/my-project/upload/'; 

/*
```