# Undefined index: file error in HOSTINGER shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, ionic4, shared-hosting

I have below code for file upload. This is working in my localhost with the IP address. But it's not working in shared hosting that is Hostinger. It's showing below error. Please help.

> Undefined index: file {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: file at /home/u766753775/domains/nammoor.online/public_html/laravel/routes/web.php:527)

IONIC 4:

```
    async CameraImageUploadwithoutCrop() {
      await this.imagePicker.getPictures({ maximumImagesCount: 1, outputType: 0 }).then((results) => {
        for (const image of results) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + image);
            const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
            const uploadOpts: FileUploadOptions = {
                fileKey: 'file',
                fileName: image.substr(image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            };

            fileTransfer.upload(image, 'https://nammoor.online/post/uploadImage', uploadOpts)
            // fileTransfer.upload(image, 'http://191.168.01.10:8000/post/uploadImage', uploadOpts)
              .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.respData = JSON.parse(data.response);
                console.log(this.respData);
                this.imageUrl = this.respData.fileUrl;
              }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });

        }
      }, (err) => { console.log(err); });
    }
```

PHP:

```
          Route::post('/post/uploadImage', function (Request $request) {

      // Route::post('image-upload', )->name('image.upload.post');
      $connection = OpenCon();
      $request = Request::instance(); // Access the instance
      $content = $request->getContent(); // Get its content
      // p($request);

    $date = date('dmYHis');
    $target_path = "uploads/images/".$date.".jpg";

        try {
          //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

            //$fileUrl = "http://191.168.01.10:8000/".$target_path."";
            $fileUrl = "https://nammoor.online/".$target_path."";

            $eRes = json_encode('{ "fileUrl": "'.$fileUrl.'"}', true);
            p($fileUrl);
            $msg = json_decode($eRes ,true);
            p($msg);
            return $msg;
          } else {
          echo $target_path;
          } 
            }
          }, (err) => { console.log(err); });
        }
```

Comment: Check this ans - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216249/9088454

Comment: I checkd the answer.But i am using Lavel based PHP. In that appilication there is no config.php file

except file upload , everithing working fine. i am strucking up in this issue for last two weeks